# Is it possible to store Multiple input field values in one single session storage and retrieve in the second page using Session Storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a query on session storage how to store three fields value  in a single session storage. I have three fields two radio button (in different groups) and one drop down in the first page this is how my first will look like. I was not able to get multiple field.

For example if user select **pg** from first radio group,**aa** from the second radio group and **DIP EDU** from the drop down third field where i need to store these values as a single session-storage from first page and i need to get the value from the first page and  in the second page based on this value i need to show the div. I don't no how store multiple field value in one session storage still i tried a bit from OS users idea.  But I am not getting the result :(

```
<div class="edu">
   <input type="radio" id="ug" name="edu" class="ug" value="ug" checked="checked">
   <label class="radio-label">Undergraduate</label>
   <input type="radio" id="pg" name="edu" value="pg" class="pg">
   <label class="radio-label">Postgraduate</label>
   <input type="radio" id="cu" name="edu" value="cu" class="cu">
   <label class="radio-label">Continuing Education</label>                          
</div>
```

And My second div consist of another set of radio button

```
 <div class="rad_cam">
   <input id="ad" class="ad" type="radio" name="cam" value="ad" checked>
   <label class="radio-label">AD</label>
   <input id="AA" class="AA" type="radio" name="cam" value="AA">
   <label class="radio-label">AA</label>
 </div>
<select class="mslt_Field slt_mjrpg ipt_required" id="slt_mjrpg" name="slt_mjrpg">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value="Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching ">DIP EDU</option>
   <option value="Master of Science in Finance ">MASF</option>
   <option value="MBA">MBA 2013</option>
</select>
```

In my second page I have simple div where i need to show a label.

```
 <div>Second page</div>
```

With my current jQuery code in the first page

```
function storedata(){
alert("check");
var storeDate = {},key,val;
key = $('#pg,#alain').attr('id');
val = $('#pg,#alain').is(':checked');
storeDate[key] = val;   
sessionStorage.setItem('storeDate', JSON.stringify(storeDate));
console.log(key);
}
```

and I am calling the function in next button

this is my second page jquery code

```
var otherObj = JSON.parse(session.getItem('storeDate'));
    if(otherObj.ug && otherObj.alain){
        alert("check");
    }
```

But I am getting ReferenceError: session is not defined kindly please let me know what i am doing wrong here

whether my storing json data in jquery is that wrong or ...... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do, but it seems you're expecting to get both `pg` and `alain` values using `$('#pg, #alain')` and you treat radio buttons as check boxes, but that doesn't work.

this code should work for saving the values

```
function storedata() {
  var storeDate = {};

  // get the id of the selected radio button
  storeDate['storedValue1'] = $('input[name=edu]:checked').val();
  storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('input[name=cam]:checked').val();

  // save the item
  sessionStorage.setItem('storeDate', JSON.stringify(storeDate));
  console.log(storeDate);
}
```

And this code can retrieve the saved value

```
var otherObj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storeDate'));
if (otherObj.storedValue1 && otherObj.storedValue2) {
  console.log(otherObj);
}
```

Comment: here I can able to store single field value not multiple :(

Comment: @Mahadevan All the radio buttons in the same group represent only one value, the `edu` value in this case. Use checkboxes if you want to represent different values

Comment: i have two groups in the first group i have to select one radio button and in second group i have to select another radio button and finally drop down

Comment: storeDate['storedValue'] = $('input[id=pg]:checked').val(); then i am trying storeDate['storedValue'] = $('input[id=alain]:checked').val();

Comment: @Mahadevan do the same for every radio group. Select them by name, not by id

Comment: hi i am not using any id now but i guess the value is not storing in storeDate :(

Comment: and i am getting warning Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent. in my second page

Comment: hi how to call in the second page 

if (otherObj.storedValue1) && (otherObj.storedValue2) {
  console.log(otherObj);
}

this would be correct

Comment: I m not gettint the console value

Comment: console.log(otherObj);

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your input data into an object and then use JSON string to store it under one key. You have to use JSON lib. https://bestiejs.github.io/json3/#section_3

`var yourData = {}, key, val;
key = $('input.ug').attr('id');
val = $('input.ug').is(':checked');
yourData[key] = val;`

You can collect all the key, value pairs using jquery.
e.g. `$('input').map(function(index, ele) { console.log(ele); });`
You can perform appropriate operation on "ele" for getting required attributes, and store in yourData object.

Finally, you can store the data under one key.
`sessionStorage.setItem('yourKey', JSON.stringify(yourData));`
And get the JSON string back, and parse it to an object.
`var otherObj = JSON.parse(session.getItem('yourKey'))`
Now you can perform checks: `if(otherObj.ug) { ... }`

Comment: thanks for the effort so it is not possible with simple sesion storage I have to use json for this can you please provide some sample with my code

Comment: when i tried your code in the second page i am getting key : storeData value : undefined;False kindly please look the same